# In what kinds of situation we are using Random /Random order controller?

Tags: random, controller, jmeter, controllers

In what kinds of situation we are using Random,Random order controller?

Answer (score 0):

Random Controller:

- Use it when you want to randomly execute ONE of its children

Random Order Controller:

- Use it when you want to execute ALL its children but in a random order

See reference docs:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Order_Controller